# Table Layout Panel and docked panel not adjusting

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I have a C# winforms application that has table layout panel. The panel is set so that there are two columns, with a 75/25 % split. In the larger section is a docked panel that holds some controls, while the smaller section has a docked panel with a single label. We push a wall of text to the label on the right and it is getting jammed up ugly.

[image]

I've adjusted the controls on the large section and recovered some space that I want to give over to the label panel. The "Completed" and "Inspected" labels and dropdowns are not in use, and set to invisible currently. I used designer to adjust the split on the table layout panel to be 65/35 %, but the docked panel and the label didn't change position on the layout.

What I want to happen is for the table layout panel to have a larger portion of the split given over to the label and the label to fill the new space when text is set to it.

The results of my efforts haven't gone very far. I adjusted the split %, but the label looks unchanged. It seems to be the exact same size it was before making changes. It looks like the label maintained the same position as well, stuck to the right hand border of the panel. The label definately isn't extending past where it originally ended/started with the 75/25 split.

The sub panel and the label are set up to fill and anchor top/left. The panel is docked to the table layout panel. I was under the impression that the docking and filling would account for the change in the split, but I'm wrong about that I guess. I feel like this whole problem has some root in these settings, but my tinkering with them hasn't changed anything that I can tell.

[image]

Comment: I stumbled across a comment that explained how nested panels work and that gave me an idea. What I've done now is changed the "intermediate" panel to anchor top right. I manually extended the width of that panel to fill the table layout panels right column. Now with the label set to fill I am seeing the panel adjust, but the text is still scrunched up.

Comment: After reading this post twice, I'm still not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion then. Look to the screenshot with arrows. The green text at the yellow arrow is scrunched up over to the right. I want it to stretch across to the space covered by the blue arrow.

Comment: Then you don't want 75 / 25%.  Set the right panel to 100% and set the Left panel to Absolute and the width of your controls — that is, set the width to match the right edge of that red delete button you have.

Comment: That did it. Thank you Lars!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the instructions provided by LarsTech, I adjusted the settings on the layout panel to be absolute pixel value on the left hand side and 100% on the right. I then set the panel anchor to top, right. I set the label itself to dock = fill. The label is now stretching across the entire area covered by the blue arrow.

Thanks again. Would give a +1 to your comment if I could.